# Python script to run an exe file with multiple parameters

Tags: python

I am a beginner in Python. I wanted to run an exe file with a number of parameters to be passed. The some parameters are path to files and some are just strings. The path for the exe also has spaces in it. I could run it via command prompt as below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX 8.0\bin\xxx.exe -I -c "E:\files" -m ASCII -lib "" -i "E:\Trialtest\input.txt" -t "E:\test\output.txt" -s "E:\Trialtest\test\output.struct"
```

I tried a lot of posts nothing worked. I found one post which is similar to my query. But didnt work for me. Please help me run this using Python.

The code i tried is

```
subprocess.check_output(["C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx_x\yyy 8.0\bin\abc.exe", "-I", "-c", "E:\Trialtest.gtp", "-m", "ASCII ", "-lib", "", "-i", "E:\Trialtest\input.txt", "-t", "E:\Trialtest\test\output.txt", "-s", "E:\Trialtest\test\output.struct"])
```

the error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#73>", line 1, in <module>
    subprocess.check_output(["C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx_x\yyy 8.0\bin\abc.exe", "-I", "-c", "E:\Trialtest.gtp", "-m", "ASCII ", "-lib", "", "-i", "E:\Trialtest\input.txt", "-t", "E:\Trialtest\test\output.txt", "-s", "E:\Trialtest\test\output.struct"])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 566, in check_output
    process = Popen(stdout=PIPE, *popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module

Comment: Tried that too. But getting errors.

Comment: @SaravanaMurthy Add that to your post. Both the code AND the traceback.

Comment: subprocess is perfect you just have to pass param correctly, checking escape and all.

Comment: Maybe you'll want to try os.popen(your_command).read() ?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to use subprocess

```
subprocess.check_output(["C:\Program Files (x86)\XXX 8.0\bin\xxx.exe", "-I", "-c", "E:\files", "-m", "ASCII", "-lib","" ,"-i", "E:\Trialtest\input.txt" ,"-t" ,"E:\test\output.txt", "-s", "E:\Trialtest\test\output.struct"])
```